# cycle through spans on jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<div id="facts">
<p>notes:</p><span class="hide">note 1</span>
             <span class="hide">note 2</span>
             <span class="hide">note 3</span>
             <span class="hide">note 4</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a simple 'slideshow' looping cycle that shows only one span to the right of the 'fact:' at a time but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work properly.

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: inline;
}
```

I'm thinking you could just add/remove classes using jquery?

Comment: You may want to see my answer to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003205/issues-recalling-an-animation-function-whilst-making-a-jquery-image-gallery-nex/11003786#11003786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery `.hide()`, you can first hide all of them. Then increment a variable on click, and compare its value to `% 4` where 4 is the total number of available spans.  Unhide the `:eq()` for the variable's current value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 0;

    // This is bound to the onclick, but you can attach it to any event.
    $('#facts').click(function() {
      // Hide all of them
      $('#facts span').hide();
      // Unhide the current one:
      $('#facts span:eq(' + (current % 4) + ')').show();
      // Increment the variable;
      current++;
    });
});
```

​
[Here is a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tnJ7e/4/)

Note that if the number of child `<span>` varies, you would want to use `$('#facts span').length` as the modulo `%` comparison rather than the hard-coded 4 as in:

```
$('#facts span:eq(' + (current % $('#facts span').length) + ')').show();
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why didn't you initially use .length?

Comment: @jacob Only because I was having trouble getting the jsfiddle example to work as I wanted it to, and the 4 is a little clearer in the code if you were not familiary with the purpose of the `%` operator.  Neither is a good reason.

Comment: I tweaked things a bit — I'd like to loose the paragraph tag (which probably won't effect anything but I'm not 100% sure) and for some reason, it's taking me two clicks for it to start cycling?

Comment: @jacob http://jsfiddle.net/tnJ7e/5/ I made some small changes in the fiddle (though not above). Your 2 clicks were probably due to the counter initializing to zero instead of 1

Comment: actually, one last thing, if it's not too much trouble — i'd like for the first span to only be seen once and after it's clicked, it won't appear in the cycle ( the first span will say something like 'click to cycle' )

Comment: @jacob That's kind of far outside the scope of your original question. You should ask a new question, posting the code you currently are using and how you would like it to behave. If you reply here when you have done so, I can look at it.

Comment: Okay here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223700/cycle-through-spans-on-jquery-click-removing-the-first-child

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` function:

```
var $spans = $('span'), i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
     if (i == $spans.length) i = 0;
     $spans.hide().eq(i).show()
     i++   
}, 2000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Chyuw/

Comment: thanks for your answer — I realize I worded my question differently than the title suggests but I was looking for a solution that would cycle on click, but I do greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have a function with a basic counting variable, and an if statement to reset the variable. You can use the `:eq()` selector to select elements like an array.

```
i = 0;
$('element').click(function() {
  $('span').hide();
  $('span:eq(i)').show(); // shows only the one indexed span tag
  i++;
  if (i > [amount of span tags]) { // resets i if it gets too big
    i = 0; 
  }
}
```

So basically you are just continually iterating through.