# Check spans and remove the first-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, html

Basically, this advances to the next hidden span when clicked.

The markup:

```
<div id="facts">
    <span>click to cycle</span>
    <span>fact 1</span>
    <span>fact 2</span>
    <span>fact 3</span>
    <span>fact 4</span>
</div>
```

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 1;
          $('#facts span').click(function() {
              // Hide all of them
              $('#facts span').hide();
              // Unhide the current one:
              $('#facts span:eq(' + (current % $('#facts span').length) + ')').show();
              // Increment the variable
              console.log(current % 4);
              current++;
          });

    // Unhide the first one on load
    $('#facts span:first-child').show();
});​
```

What I'm trying to do now is remove the first span after it's been clicked, because it is not necessary for the user to see the 'click to cycle' instruction again.

Comment: Which span do you want to hide? The 'click to cycle' one?

Comment: `<span class="remove-me"> ... $(".remove-me").remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a specific id to the original one and a class to the others.

```
<span id='removeme'>click to cycle</span>
<span class='cycleme'>fact 1</span>
<span class='cycleme'>fact 2</span>
<span class='cycleme'>fact 3</span>
<span class='cycleme'>fact 4</span>
```

Show the `removeme` and hide all the others via CSS

```
#removeme {
  display: inline;
}
span.cycleme {
  display: none;
}
```

In the script, bind a click event to the original one to simply remove it. The subsequent ones get the same handler as they had before.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialize
    var current = 1;

   // Bind the first one's onclick to remove itself
   $('#removeme').click(function() {
      $(this).remove();
      // And display the first one
      $('#facts span:first-child').show();
   });


   // Target the others via their class
   $('#facts span.cycleme').click(function() {
      // Hide all of them
      $('#facts span').hide();
      // Unhide the current one:
      $('#facts span:eq(' + (current % $('#facts span.cycleme').length) + ')').show();
      // Increment the variable
      current++;
   });
});​
```

[Here is the live example](http://jsfiddle.net/tnJ7e/7/)

Comment: Perhaps unhide the first `.cycleme` only when `#removeme` is removed?

Comment: @JanDvorak Misunderstood you originally. It didn't show on ready in the fiddle because all <span> were hidden.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Markdown what language it should be syntax-highlighting?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think so, but I usually evade it by putting plain text between html and JS blocks...

Comment: It misguessed the CSS this time ;-)

Comment: This doesnt work, he wants the 'cycle click' removed on any span click

Comment: @VIDesignz there's nothing to remove on subsequent clicks. He wants to remove the span that was _originally_ the first

Comment: @Jan  Once any span is clicked, the only one he wants to remove is the 'click to cycle' This code only has the 'click to cycle' removed if you click the 'click to cycle' span.

Comment: @VIDesignz only 'click to cycle' can be clicked before 'click to cycle' is removed.

Comment: All I had to do was add a class to the first span and have jquery remove it when the :first-child was clicked

Comment: $('#facts span:first-child').click(function() {
$(".remove-me").remove();
});

Comment: I see, the 'click to cyle' is misleading though...first you click that, it disappears, then you have to click the only showing span to continue to cycle?? This may be confusing to users.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/KDMaK/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="facts">
    <span id='remove'>click to cycle</span>
    <span>fact 1</span>
    <span>fact 2</span>
    <span>fact 3</span> 
   <span>fact 4</span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 1;
          $('#facts span').click(function() {
              $('#remove').remove();
              // Hide all of them
              $('#facts span').hide();
              // Unhide the current one:
              $('#facts span:eq(' + (current % $('#facts span').length) + ')').show();// Increment the variable
              console.log(current % 4);
              current++;
          });

    // Unhide the first one on load
    $('#facts span:first-child').show();
});
```

Comment: The log is not really useful if there are not exactly four spans

Comment: That is not my doing...I only removed 'click to cycle'